# Jax: generating random numbers under **JIT**

Tags: python, random, equinox, jax

I have a setup where I need to generate some random number that is consumed by `vmap` and then `lax.scan` later on:

```py
def generate_random(key: Array, upper_bound: int, lower_bound: int) -> int:
    ...
    return num.astype(int)

def forward(key: Array, input: Array) -> Array:
    k = generate_random(key, 1, 5)
    computation = model(.., k, ..)
    ...

# Computing the forward pass
output = jax.vmap(forward, in_axes=.....
```

But attempting to convert `num` from a `jax.Array` to an `int32` causes the `ConcretizationError`.

This can be reproduced through this **minimal example**:

```py
@jax.jit
def t():
  return jnp.zeros((1,)).item().astype(int)

o = t()
o
```

JIT requires that all the manipulations be of the Jax type.

But `vmap` uses JIT implicitly. And I would prefer to keep it for performance reasons.

---

#### My Attempt

This was my hacky attempt:

```py
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1, 2))
def get_rand_num(key: Array, lower_bound: int, upper_bound: int) -> int:
  key, subkey = jax.random.split(key)
  random_number = jax.random.randint(subkey, shape=(), minval=lower_bound, maxval=upper_bound)
  return random_number.astype(int)

def react_forward(key: Array, input: Array) -> Array:
  k = get_rand_num(key, 1, MAX_ITERS)
  # forward pass the model without tracking grads
  intermediate_array = jax.lax.stop_gradient(model(input, k)) # THIS LINE ERRORS OUT
  ...
  return ...

a = jnp.zeros((300, 32)).astype(int)
rndm_keys = jax.random.split(key, a.shape[0])
jax.vmap(react_forward, in_axes=(0, 0))(rndm_keys, a).shape
```

Which involves creating the `batch_size` # of subkeys to use at every batch during `vmap` (`a.shape[0]`) thus getting random numbers.

But it doesn't work, because of the `k` being casted from `jax.Array -> int`.

But making these changes:

> ```
> -  k = get_rand_num(key, 1, MAX_ITERS)
> +  k = 5 # any hardcoded int
> ```

Works perfectly. Clearly, the sampling is causing the problem here...

---

#### Clarifications

To not make this into an X-Y problem I'll clearly define what I want precisely:

I'm implementing a version of stochastic depth; basically, my `model`'s forward pass can accept a `depth: int` at runtime which is the length of a `scan` run internally - specifically, the `xs = jnp.arange(depth)` for the `scan`.

I want my architecture to flexibly adapt to different depths. Therefore, at training time, I need a way to produce pseudorandom numbers that would equal the `depth`.

So I require a function, that on **every** call to it (such is the case in `vmap`) it returns a different number, sampled within some bound: `depth ∈ [1, max_iters]`.

The function has to be `jit`-able (implicit requirement of `vmap`) and has to produce an `int` - as that's what fed into `jnp.arange` later (*Workarounds that directly get `generate_random` to produce an `Array` of `jnp.arange(depth)` without converting to a static value might be possible*)

> (I have no idea honestly how others do this; this seems like a common enough want, especially if one's dealing with sampling during train time)

I've attached the error traceback generated by my "hacky solution attempt" if that helps...

```bash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ConcretizationTypeError                   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-32-d6ff062f5054> in <cell line: 16>()
     14 a = jnp.zeros((300, 32)).astype(int)
     15 rndm_keys = jax.random.split(key, a.shape[0])
---> 16 jax.vmap(react_forward, in_axes=(0, 0))(rndm_keys, a).shape

    [... skipping hidden 3 frame]

4 frames

<ipython-input-32-d6ff062f5054> in react_forward(key, input)
      8   k = get_rand_num(key, 1, MAX_ITERS)
      9   # forward pass the model without tracking grads
---> 10   intermediate_array = jax.lax.stop_gradient(model(input, iters_to_do=k))
     11   # n-k passes, but track the gradient this time
     12   return model(input, MAX_ITERS - k, intermediate_array)

    [... skipping hidden 12 frame]

<ipython-input-22-4760d53eb89c> in __call__(self, input, iters_to_do, prev_thought)
     71       #interim_thought = self.main_block(interim_thought)
     72 
---> 73     interim_thought = self.iterate_for_steps(interim_thought, iters_to_do, x)
     74 
     75     return self.out_head(interim_thought)

    [... skipping hidden 12 frame]

<ipython-input-22-4760d53eb89c> in iterate_for_steps(self, interim_thought, iters_to_do, x)
     56         return self.main_block(interim_thought), None
     57 
---> 58     final_interim_thought, _ = jax.lax.scan(loop_body, interim_thought, jnp.arange(iters_to_do))
     59     return final_interim_thought
     60 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py in arange(start, stop, step, dtype)
   2286     util.check_arraylike("arange", start)
   2287     if stop is None and step is None:
-> 2288       start = core.concrete_or_error(None, start, "It arose in the jnp.arange argument 'stop'")
   2289     else:
   2290       start = core.concrete_or_error(None, start, "It arose in the jnp.arange argument 'start'")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jax/_src/core.py in concrete_or_error(force, val, context)
   1379       return force(val.aval.val)
   1380     else:
-> 1381       raise ConcretizationTypeError(val, context)
   1382   else:
   1383     return force(val)

ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: traced array with shape int32[].
It arose in the jnp.arange argument 'stop'
This BatchTracer with object id 140406974192336 was created on line:
  <ipython-input-32-d6ff062f5054>:8 (react_forward)

See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError
```

Really appreciate you helping me out here. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The random numbers you are generating are *traced*; in other words, they are known only at runtime (your mental model of "runtime" should be "operations running on the XLA device").

Python integers, on the other hand, are *static*; in other words, they must be defined at compile time (your mental model of "compile time" should be "operations that happen before runtime values are known").

With this framing, it's clear that you cannot convert a traced value to a static Python integer within `jit`, `vmap` or any other JAX transform, because static values must be known before the traced values are determined. Where this comes up in your minimal example is in the call to `.item()`, which attempts to cast a (traced) JAX array to a (static) Python scalar.

You can fix this by avoiding this cast. Here is a new version of your function that returns a zero-dimensional integer array, which is how JAX encodes an integer scalar at runtime:

```py
@jax.jit
def t():
  return jnp.zeros((1,)).astype(int).reshape(())
```

That said, the fact that you are so concerned with creating an integer from an array makes me think that your `model` function requires its second argument to be static, and unfortunately the above won't help you in that case. For the reasons discussed above **it is impossible to convert a traced value within a JAX transformation into a static value**.

---

Edit: the issue you're running into is the fact that [JAX arrays must have static shapes](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#dynamic-shapes). In your code, you're generating random integers at runtime, and attempting to pass them to `jnp.arange`, which would result in a dynamically-shaped array. It is not possible to execute such code within transformations like `jit` or `vmap`.

Fixing this usually involves writing your code in a way that supports the dynamic computation size (for example, creating a padded array of a maximum size, or using `jax.fori_loop` in place of `jax.scan`).

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer. I've edited the post with a bit of clarification specifying exactly what I'm looking for. Simply put, when `vmap`-ing across batches, I'd like to sample a new integer within some bound for every batch. This is helpful in training my model to be more robust to changes :) So the requirement is for a `JIT`-able function, that returns random integers...

Comment: `fori_loop` seems to embody the exact operation I want to do. But would the performance suffer vs. `scan`? any other downsides/side-effects I should be aware of when using `fori_loop`? (in my case, only the `upper` bound changes every batch.

Also, more importantly, I'll still need to sample the `upper` bound between `1` and `MAX_ITERS`, so we're back to square one I guess..

Comment: The main difference is that when you have a dynamic upper bound, you can no longer use reverse-mode autodiff

Comment: That's a bummer... maybe then I can just `lax.cond` in there somewhere to apply a stop gradient after some iterations, but keep the `upper` bound fixed/static. 
but even then, I *still* need an alternative to `numpy.random.randint` that actually returns an `int`!

Comment: You may want to look into `jax.checkpoint` if you use `jax.lax.cond` to apply the identity operator and make the loop bound static. There is the bounded while loop in `diffrax`, and perhaps you could hide dynamic looping using `custom_root`. Also, to can cast between numpy and native Python without issue.

Comment: You need to stop focusing on generating an `int` within a JIT runtime: it is categorically impossible. This is an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you're trying to solve X; you get stuck on a subtask Y that you assume is necessary. The bad news is that in this case, Y is impossible. The good news is, your assumption that Y is necessary for X is probably wrong. But you need to focus on (and ask about) your actual problem X, rather than continuing to get stuck on Y.

Comment: @DavidJ I tried using `np.random.randint` with JIT - it works well for forward, but I'm unsure how well Jax would handle backprop with it.

Comment: @jakevdp I understand, but I've outlined my case; I have a single stack of layers, and every batch I want to forward (and backprop) through the same stack `iters` times. To get my arch handling length flexibly, I want to use different no. of `iters` everytime. Hence sampling the `depth/iters` within some bound specified above. If it helps, the arch is very similar to a DEQ. Obviously, pytorch makes it easy but inefficient due to recompilation of the dynamic graph. But it's a whole other ballgame with Jax....

Comment: Note that `np.random.randint` under JIT will execute once at compile-time, and use the same "random" integer for every subsequent function call – it's probably not the behavior you want. For solving your X problem, I'd probably use a fixed-length procedure at each iteration that can be cut off at a dynamic number of steps. It's hard to go deeper in an answer comment thread – I'd suggest opening a new SO question focusing on the main problem.

Comment: > that can be cut off at a dynamic number of steps.... Exactly, my problem is how do you generate a number of "dynamic steps"? That's an `int` too, I take which brings us back full circle

Comment: I could explain more, but a deep comment thread on a loosely-related question is not a very easy place to do it.

Comment: Cool, I'll do that tmrw. In the meantime, @jakevdp I think the simplest solution would be to pregenerate some (static) list of integers within the bound (`len = # of batches`) and pass it along to `vmap`. So each batch gets a different number of iterations... I had that in mind, but I thought there was some even simpler way than that tbh..

Comment: @DavidJ That might work; I can access the iteration index through the `body_fn`; but my main, core problem remains - how do I generate a bunch of random numbers and pass it to `body_fn` for each iteration..

Comment: If you vmap over an array the values will no longer be static, because vmap traces the computation.

Comment: I used `partial`'s `static_argnums` to specify that `iters` is a `static` argument, and it seems to work fine with a `fori_loop` @jakevdp

Comment: Ok, I don’t understand how that would work in this context, but code is generally hard to understand if you can’t see it. I’d suggest a new SO post if you still have questions